# My UI is being shown twice in the same window

Tags: java

[Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWNej.jpg)

My Jtextfields and Jbuttons are being duplicated in the same window, and appear to function exactly the same.

This is probably an easy fix, but as you can tell I'm pretty awful at coding.

(oh and some of the names for variables and such are placeholders :p)

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Adding extends JFrame {
  public Adding(Heavy_Lifting lifting) {
    addUI(lifting);
  }

  public void addUI(final Heavy_Lifting lifting) {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JButton addButton = new JButton("Enter");
    JButton backButton = new JButton("Quit");
    final JTextField eInput = new JTextField("Enter english name");
    final JTextField mInput = new JTextField("Enter maori name");
    final JTextField dInput = new JTextField("Enter description");

    //add(addButton);
    //add(eInput);
    //add(mInput);
    //add(backButton);
    //add(dInput);

    Dimension x = new Dimension(500, 50);

    //addButton.setText("Enter");
    addButton.setPreferredSize(x);

    //backButton.setText("Quit");
    backButton.setPreferredSize(x);

    //eInput.setText("Enter english name");
    eInput.setPreferredSize(x);

    //mInput.setText("Enter maori name");
    mInput.setPreferredSize(x);

    //dInput.setText("Enter description");
    dInput.setPreferredSize(x);

    add(addButton);
    add(eInput);
    add(mInput);
    add(dInput);
    add(backButton);

    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {@
      Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String mname = mInput.getText();
        String ename = eInput.getText();
        String desc = dInput.getText();
        PeePee p = new PeePee(mname);
        Description d = new Description(desc);
        if (lifting.allChar(ename, p)) {
          lifting.insert(ename, p);
          lifting.insert(ename, d);
          eInput.setText("1");
          mInput.setText("2");
          dInput.setText("3");
        } else {
          eInput.setText("4");
          mInput.setText("5");
          dInput.setText("6");
        }
      }
    });

    backButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {@
      Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        setVisible(false);
      }
    });

    setTitle("placeholder");
    setSize(550, 300);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(550, 300));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code example runs just fine for me. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your public method `addUI` is called twice, maybe by another class. Try switch it to private and see if it still runs and produces the same visual output.

Comment: Then please let other users that may stumble upon this question know what the problem was and how you solved it.